# Vaio VPCSA Battery Not Detected

Tags: bios, battery, sony-vaio

Out of nowhere my Vaio VPCSA stopped detecting the battery. My battery was working fine. I was getting a couple hours of streaming video on just the battery. Then last night, while on AC, the battery status in the status bar switched to "No battery is detected" and the battery charging LED is off. I've tried the following to correct the issue:

- Unplugged AC, removed the battery, and pressed the power button to drain all power
- Uninstalled the "Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery" driver
- Switched over to Manjaro Linux and the battery is not detected there
- Plugged in my extended battery which is also not detected
- I suspect the issue is with the BIOS, but Sony's BIOS Update Utility just says I have the most recent version

Does anyone have any other ideas? Is there any way I can completely re-install the BIOS?

Thank you for your help,
Josh

Comment: Good batteries have 3 built in curcuit protection methods, and 2 physical cell protections that can cut power. Cheap clone batteries do not always have all the proper protection, and can cut out via cell protection. Given the description you provdided, I would want to voltmeter (at least) the battery before messing with anything else. It is possible (both cheap and oem) for a single cell item to have been internally disconnected as a protection method used on cylyndrical cells.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I doubt it's a problem with the battery though. It's unlikely that both of my batteries became undetectable.

Comment: Good point. You had changed nothing when it failed this way? It fails in 2 different OSes the same way.  Both batteries fail. The AC adapter still supplies sufficient power for operation? Does the bios itself show any information about the battery?  How would the bios be involved once the 2 operating systems have been handed off to?

Comment: Thank you for your input. Originally I thought the battery had to be recognized by the bios before being handed off to the OS, but after some research that doesn't seem to be the case. I can't think of anything that would have damaged the physical machine, but I'm starting to suspect the hardware connecting to the battery may have failed. I have no idea what else could be the problem.

Comment: Yes , the charge curcuit (in the computer) or connection to the battery

Comment: If you move your response to an answer, I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: If you fixed the problem or When you fix the problem you could self answer.